# how to write queries using python and REST to retrieve data from JIRA

Tags: python, rest, jira, jql

I am trying to create a script using python and REST to  get data from JIRA,currently am able to get data for each JIRA ticket using the code shown below,I want to be able to write queries to retrieve large data which I do currently from the UI as shown below,how can I update my current script to achieve this from the script?

Query:
    "project = ITTICKETS AND "Build Info" ~ CI_-STD.INT-2"

Python code:-

```
import requests
import json
import logging
import datetime
import base64
serverURL = 'https://jira.company.com/jira'
user = 'username'
password = 'password'
jql = '/rest/api/2/issue/JIRATICKET-152133'
response = requests.get(serverURL + jql,verify=False,auth=(user, password))
print response
#print response.data
print response.json()
```

Comment: You should probably read the "User Authentication" section in the [JIRA REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-version-2-tutorial) documentation.

Comment: David - I already have access to the server ,not sure how your comment is related to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `jql` like this:

```
import urllib
query = 'project = ITTICKETS AND "Build Info" ~ CI_-STD.INT-2'
jql = '/rest/api/2/search?jql=%s' % urllib.quote(query)
```